# Algorithm to get a Regex

Tags: regex

Something like this is on my mind: I put one or a few strings in, and the algorithm shows me a matching regex.

Is there an "*easy*" way to do this, or does something like this already exist?

***Edit 1***: Yes, I'm trying to find a way to generate regex.

***Edit 2***: Regulazy is not what I am looking for. The common use for the code I want is to find a correct RegEx; for example, article numbers:

- I put in *123456*, the regex should be `\d{6}`
- I put in *nb-123456*, the regex should be `\w{2}-\d{6}`

Comment: IMO, the solutions to this problem will not be predictive, it is like finding factors for a given number. The input data still plays a major role in the output. For ex: given  an input 'list' we can have .*, \w*, \w+, \w{4}, \w{2}\w{2}... (yes, wierd but possible). Interesting question though.

Comment: Answer to [Generate RegEx from matches](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12068327/471214)

Answer (score 3):

If you have Emacs you can use `regexp-opt`.  For example, evaluating:

```
(regexp-opt (list "my" "list" "of" "some" "strings" "to" "search"))
```

returns

```
"list\\|my\\|of\\|s\\(?:earch\\|ome\\|trings\\)\\|to"
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want an algorithm to generate a regular grammar based on some samples. In a lot of cases, there are many possible grammars for a given set of examples--there can even be infinite possible grammars. Of course, the possibilities can be limited by a second set of required **non**-matches, which can limit it to zero possibilities if the non-matching strings are too inclusive.

**[txt2re](http://txt2re.com/)** does something like this.

Comment: txt2re looks there to me!  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Perl can do it: http://www.hakank.org/makeregex/

So does ruby: http://www.toolbox-mag.de/data/makeregex.html

Note: not so perfect solution.

And there is a CLI tool: [txt2regex](http://txt2regex.sourceforge.net/).

There was [txt2re, once upon a time](http://209.85.135.104/search?q=cache:0govuS1Vj8EJ:txt2re.com/+txt2re&hl=hu&ct=clnk&cd=1&gl=hu)...

Answer (score 1):

How about the following (matches every string)?

.*

Answer (score 1):

I think that Regulazy by Roy Osherove does this to a certain extent, or it may be Regulator. BOth are on this page:

http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/pages/tools-and-frameworks-by-roy-osherove.aspx

Answer (score 0):

if your input strings are not random strings and they are based on some rules, by using a parser (i.e. jflex), you can create a regex generator which will generate a regex w.r.t. the given strings.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [txt2re](http://txt2re.com).

This site holds a form that takes a sample string and generates a regex pattern that can match the given string.

Then it generates the corresponding script for the following languages: Perl, PHP, Python, Java, Javascript, ColdFusion, C, C++     Ruby, VB, VBScript, J#.net, C#.net, C++.net, VB.net